# What is an active centre of a catalyst?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis

I was studying catalytic poisoning and read that in temporary poisoning, the poisoners are held at active centres by weak forces.

What is an 'active centre' in this context?

Comment: Same as "active sites" or where the catalyzed reaction takes place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The active centre is the site where the substrate binds to the catalyst in order for catalysis to take place. On a molecular level, most catalysts (or most substances really) are not just flat surfaces, they have complex three dimensional shapes. The substrate often has to bind to the catalyst in a very specific way in order for the catalysed reaction to take place - this is the active centre.